# CABasicAnimation animationDidStart did called, but animationDidStop never was

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer, ios-animations

I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446127/cabasicanimation-animationdidstop-not-called) a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572835/core-animation-animationdidstop-not-called) of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978915/animationdidstop-not-being-called) about this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152045/animationdidstop-set-but-not-being-called-iphone-app-coding), but can not solve my particular case.

[Here is a video with complete animation and logging timeline](https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=0RxLhEW6t38YMlVocNo6Ap5pXHjyyE)

```
class AnimationDelegate: UIView {

    deinit {
        print("AnimationDelegate deinitialized")
    }

    override func animationDidStart(anim: CAAnimation) {
        print("animationDidStart")
    }

    override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        print("animationDidStop")
    }

    func play() {
        let line_1 = CAShapeLayer()
        ...

        let animation = CABasicAnimation()
        animation.delegate = self
        animation.duration = 3000
        animation.repeatCount = 1
        animation.keyPath = "strokeEnd"
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 360

        layer.addSublayer(line_1)
        line_1.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "StrokeAnimation")

    }
}

let delegate = AnimationDelegate(frame: container.bounds)
container.addSubview(delegate)

delegate.play()
```

The problem is `animationDidStart` called, but `animationDidStop` not.

How this is possible?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that configures the `CABasicAnimation`.

Comment: @rob-mayoff thank you for request. i am done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `animationDidStop` will get called, had you waited longer. But this is, certainly, not the behavior you expected.

I gather that you would like to let the animation run for 3 seconds instead of 3000; and once completed, receive a notification from the delegate callback, which is `animationDidStop`.

So, instead, you would need to change:

```
animation.duration = 3
```

and:

```
animation.toValue = 1
```

Thereby, you would see that both `animationDidStart` and `animationDidStop` will get called accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Neither animationDidStart nor animationDidStop worked.

I try to work this lines in a view controller :

```
let delegate = AnimationDelegate(frame: container.bounds)
container.addSubview(delegate)

delegate.play()
```

Anitmation worked but override methods didn't work.